# Can I conditionally define a macro in Makefile in a portable way?

Tags: makefile

I've been struggling to define a macro named `DEBUG` conditionally in a portable Makefile when the target-name is *debug*.

```
.POSIX:
.SUFFIXES:

CFLAGS = -Wall -O3 $(DEBUG)

all: hello
debug: DEBUG=-O0 -g
debug: all
hello: main.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o hello main.o $(LDLIBS)
main.o: main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.c
```

It works fine on GNU Make but I can't run it on `bmake` or `fmake` (from Debian's `freebsd-buildutils`).

```
$ fmake debug
make: don't know how to make DEBUG=-O0. Stop
```

According to an ancient [SunOS Make User's Guide](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/sun/sunos/3.4/800-1620-05A_Make_Users_Guide_198705.pdf), there was a special syntax to Conditional Macro Definitions, but it just doesn't work:

```
target-name := macro = value
```

Also, I haven't found a *standard* way in the [make's official specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html).

How can I define `DEBUG` conditionally in a portable fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do it portably is via recursion:

```
debug:
        $(MAKE) all DEBUG='-O0 -g'
```

Any POSIX-compliant version of `make` will handle this properly.